# How to change the format of a single instance of `\pageref`?

Tags: cross-referencing, page, pageref

For some reason I need to format the page numbers as `S-\arabic` but want to refer to a single page using `\pageref` without including the `S-` prefix but just the `\arabic`. How to do that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{S-\arabic{page}}

There is a total of \pageref{page:last page} page in the document.

\label{page:last page}

\end{document}
```

which current produces

[image: MWE]

I would like the sentence here to print as ``...a total of 1 page...''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This removes the `S-` from string. Since `\pageref` is protected, use `\getpagerefnumber` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}% or hyperref
\usepackage{xstring}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{S-\arabic{page}}

\begin{document}

There is a total of {\StrDel{\getpagerefnumber{page:last page}}{S-}} page in the document.

\label{page:last page}

\end{document
```

Answer (score 1):

With a recent version of LaTeX you can use `\@abspage@last`.

When the value has not been set in the `.aux` file, `\maxdimen` would be returned, so for this case I use `??`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{S-\arabic{page}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\numberofpages}{%
  \ifnum\@abspage@last=\maxdimen ??\else\@abspage@last\fi
  ~page\ifnum\@abspage@last=1 \else s\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

There is a total of \numberofpages\ in the document.

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Image edited to make the page number visible.)

If you really need a `\label`, you can manually do it, using the proper hook.

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{S-\arabic{page}}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{shipout/lastpage}{%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel{LastPage}{{}{\arabic{page}}}}%
}
\makeatother

\textheight=1cm

\begin{document}

\label{test}

This is page \pageref{test}.

There is a total of \pageref{LastPage} pages in the document.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This command is certainly helpful, but what I need here is slightly different. In fact my `\label` is in a different .tex file. In the main file I use the package `xr` to reference the page located in the secondary file. More generally I would like to know if I can edit the format of a single `\pageref` instance.

Comment: @tvk I added how to add a label.